# How to get identifier declarative style kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have this code

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDButton, MDButtonText
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog, MDDialogHeadlineText, MDDialogSupportingText, MDDialogButtonContainer, \
    MDDialogContentContainer
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField, MDTextFieldLeadingIcon, MDTextFieldHelperText

KV = '''
ScreenManager:
    Screen_1:
        id: screen_1
        name: 'screen_1'


<Screen_1>
    MDScreen:
        id: screen_1
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'open dialog'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                on_press:
                    root.open_dialog()

'''


class Test(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


class Screen_1(Screen):

    def open_dialog(self):
        self.search_dialog = MDDialog(
            MDDialogHeadlineText(text='Find human'),
            MDDialogSupportingText(text="Input name"),
            MDDialogContentContainer(
                MDTextField(
                    MDTextFieldLeadingIcon(icon='magnify'),
                    MDTextFieldHelperText(text="Helper text"),
                    id='search_name',
                    mode="outlined"),
            ),
            MDDialogButtonContainer(
                Widget(),
                MDButton(
                    MDButtonText(text="Find"),
                    style="text",
                    on_release=self.dialog_search_button_click()
                ),
                spacing="8dp",
            ), id='dialog'
        )
        self.search_dialog.open()

    def dialog_search_button_click(self):
        dialog = MDDialog
        print(dialog.ids['content_container'].children[0].text)

Test().run()
```

I need to get text from inpur field in the MDDialog, but I can't understand how to get it. I know that the declarative style is no longer supported in kivy, but there is no other option in kivymd. I'll try both self and self.root, but it doesn't work

KivyMD: 2.0.1dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving a reference to the `MDTextField`. In your `open_dialog()` method, create the `MDTextField` in a separate line:

```
            self.mdtf = MDTextField(
                MDTextFieldLeadingIcon(icon='magnify'),
                MDTextFieldHelperText(text="Helper text"),
                mode="outlined")
```

Then use that in both the `open_dialog()` method:

```
    self.search_dialog = MDDialog(
        MDDialogHeadlineText(text='Find human'),
        MDDialogSupportingText(text="Input name"),
        MDDialogContentContainer(
            self.mdtf
        ),
        MDDialogButtonContainer(
            Widget(),
            MDButton(
                MDButtonText(text="Find"),
                style="text",
                on_release=self.dialog_search_button_click()
            ),
            spacing="8dp",
        )
    )
```

and in the `dialog_search_button_click()` method:

```
def dialog_search_button_click(self):
    print(self.mdtf.text)
```

Note that defining an `id` in python code will not work, it must be defined in `kv`.

Comment: It really worked. Thank You so much for your advice. P.S. Yes, I know that ids is defined only for kv-code, but as you know, some widgets in kivymd cannot be written in kvlang